# How to fetch a list of more than 500 users in Google Directory API?

Tags: java, google-api, google-directory-api

I have written a code which uses Google Directory API to fetch user accounts information from the server. It specifically fetches user list but by default, the system returns a list of 100 users in the alphabetical order of the user's email address. This can be changed by setting **Directory.Users.List.setMaxResults** to 500 (which is upper limit). But in case, I set it to more than 500, the call returns an exception.

So my question is, in case the server has more than 500 users, is it possible to fetch all the users (more than 500) in a single list? If not, is there any workaround to fetch all the users?

**NOTE-** I am using Java client library of directory api

Answer (score 0):

Use pageToken like this:

```
List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory.Users.List ul = dir.users().list().setCustomer(customerId).setMaxResults(Config.MAX_API_RESULTS);
do {
    Users curPage = ul.execute();
    usersList.addAll(curPage.getUsers());
    ul.setPageToken(curPage.getNextPageToken());
} while(ul.getPageToken() != null && ul.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the maximum page size is 500 and the allowed values are from 1 to 500.  Hence, you must be getting an exception.
For getting the next page of users, the API sends a pageToken for the next page in the response.  Use this to get the next set of 500 users and so on. 
The actual API looks like this - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list